# Delete list of Singly linked list

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I'm practicing data structures and I've implemented a code that creates a singly linked list, add to the list and delete the list. I would really like to know if my delete list function is actually doing what it should do. I think it is because when i try to print the list after the delete it crashes. So any advice on ensuring that it is deleting my list or any other advice you may have on improving my code. I'm still a bit of a rookie when it comes to dynamically allocating memory.

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
}* nodePtr;

nodePtr addToList(nodePtr head, int data) {
    nodePtr newItem = new node; //create a new item 

    newItem->data = data; //assign the data to the new item 
    newItem->next = head; //point to head

    return newItem; //return the new head
}

void deleteList(nodePtr head) {
    if (head == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        deleteList(head->next);
        delete head;
        head = nullptr;
    }
}

void Print(nodePtr n) {
    while (n != nullptr) {
        cout << n->data << " ";
        n = n->next;
    }
}

int main() {
    nodePtr head = new node;
    nodePtr second = new node;
    nodePtr third = new node;

    head->data = 1;
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 2;
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 3;
    third->next = nullptr;

    Print(head);
    cout << endl;

    head = addToList(head, 0);

    Print(head);
    cout << endl;

    deleteList(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend you should step through your code line by line with the debugger to find and fix the problem.

Comment: Your addToList is not doing what its supposed to do. Try calling delete without calling your addToList function and fix from there. In your main you are not using the addToList rather creating the list manually.

Comment: To determine whether you're correctly cleaning up what you allocated, you could try a tool like valgrind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call:

```
deleteList(head);
```

`head` won't be equal to `NULL` after that statement. Instead, you'll need to do something like:

```
deleteList(head);
head = NULL;
```

or:

```
void deleteList(nodePtr & head) {
    if (head == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        deleteList(head->next);
        delete head;
        head = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Note that we use a reference parameter for deleteList.

Answer (score 1):

your function is mostly correct besides a small caveat pointed out in Bill's answer.

I just wanted to point out that you do not really need a recursion to delete the list. Here is an alternative way.

```
while(head != nullptr) {
    node *deleteMe = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete deleteMe;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add something like this to clean up the code:

```
nodePtr create_node(int n) {
   nodePtr p = new node;
   assert (p != NULL);
   p -> data = n;
   p -> next = NULL;
}
```

This way, you could clean up your main function for testing by using a loop like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
   nodePtr p = create_node(i);
   head = addToList(head, p);
}
```

And then pass your head pointer by reference, so you would end up with something like this:

```
nodePtr addToList(nodePtr&head, nodePtr newItem) {
    newItem->next = head; //point to head
    head = newItem;
}
```

These are pretty much just style changes but it will make it easier to test your program instead of creating nodes separately in your main function, and it makes the code look a little cleaner. One other thing you could do is a try to delete this list iteratively first, once you implement that the recursive delete may make more sense.

To actually debug it and check whether you're deallocating memory correctly the best way is to use a debugger, you could add in assert( ) to verify null values, but it's worth checking out something like gdb (for command line):
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/. That tutorial is actually for debugging memory allocation for a linked list so it might be helpful.